# How to predict the motion of a cylinder on top of inclined plane in scenario with different coefficients of friction?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Consider an inclined plane with angle $x$. Now put a cylinder on top of it and consider three different cases.

1. A the limiting frictional force $f$ is greater than $mg\sin(x)$ where $m$ is the mass of cylinder.
2. B the limiting friction $f$ is exactly equal to $mg\sin(x)$
3. C it is less than $mg\sin(x)$.

What will happen in each case?

In A and B I suppose $f$ will provide torque and then friction will change direction to oppose the angular velocity maybe.

In C it will start moving and then provide torque but the friction should vanish although it stays there and apparently it may or may not cause slipping. What is meaning of slipping?

I am not sure about these cases. Can someone explain. I just need physical intuitive explanation.

Comment: The transition from slipping to not slipping will happen at a different available traction level than $m g \sin x$ because of the mass moment of inertia of the cylinder.

Comment: What are the forces acting on the cylinder beyond gravity?

Answer (score 0):

The no slipping condition is that the angular acceleration of the cylinder $\alpha$ and the translational acceleration of the centre of mass of the cylinder $a_{\rm c}$ are related as follows $a_{\rm c} = r \alpha$ where $r$ is the radius of the cylinder.

You have to decide whether or not this condition can be satisfied for differ values of the limiting frictional force.
I assume that by limiting frictional force this means the maximum static frictional force and that once slipping occurs the kinetic frictional force will be less than the limiting frictional force.

The free body diagram with the weight of the cylinder $mg$ resolved into two components looks something like this.

[image]

The forces $mg \sin x$ and $f$ are going to determine the translational acceleration of the centre of mass of the cylinder, $(F=ma_{\rm c})$, and the frictional force $f$ is going to determine the angular acceleration of the cylinder if the torque is about the centre of mass of the cylinder, $(\tau_{\rm c}= I_{\rm c}\alpha)$.

Comment: What about motion in case 1 ?

Comment: It says limiting friction is greater than $mg\sin x$.  It does not say limiting friction is equal to $mg\sin x$. Read the second sentence of my second paragraph which implies that the static frictional force can be any value from zero up the the maximum (limiting) value.

Comment: Yes but in this case what will happen to the cylinder will it stay at rest or just rotate at one place without any translatios as there is torque due to friction

Comment: Just look at the diagram. Does it look like an equilibrium situation? It might be easier to see if you replace the two components of weight with just $mg$.

Comment: There must be a translational equilibrium because a = 0

Comment: Okay forget about 1 see the 2 atleast there is a net force zero

Comment: Agreed. So what does the frictional force do about the rotation? Can you satisfy the no slip condition?

Comment: I dont know exactly I think it should give angular acceleration but he no slip condition cannot be satisfied now.

Comment: I think in this case maybe normal shifts to the left and provides torque opposite to friction And brings body to mechanical equilibrium.

Comment: I guess what im not sure about is does in case two it automatically takes its maximum limiting value or just that it takes some smaller value such that later it can satisfy no slip condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58303/discussion-between-farcher-and-raghav-singal).

Comment: I don't get it. In case 1, if friction is directed opposite to the component of gravity along the incline, it would cause a torque which would cause relative motion between the inclined plane and cylinder due to an angular velocity, which would then cause friction to start acting down the incline, which would make the cylinder to move down the incline, which would again cause friction to change direction...

Comment: The frictional force is there to provide an anticlockwise torque to provide an angular acceleration of cylinder so that its anticlockwise rotary acceleration matches the downward linear acceleration so that the cylinder does not slip.

Comment: So basically friction just serves to ensure rolling motion and it is not possible for it to keep the cylinder at rest on the incline?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a ramp that goes downhill to the left and uphill to the right. A coordinate system is placed on the cylinder center, pointing uphill and away from the ramp surface.

A free-body diagram and force consideration along the ramp and perpendicular to the ramp produces the following three equations of motion:

$$ \begin{aligned}
  T - m g \sin x & = m \dot{v} \\
 N - m g \cos x & = 0 \\
  T r & = I \dot{\omega}
\end{aligned} $$

Where $T$ is the friction force, $N$ the normal force, $r$ is the cylinder radius, $v$ the velocity *uphill*, $\omega$ the counter-clockwise rotation of the cylinder. Also $m$ is the mass and $I = \tfrac{m}{2} r^2$ the mass moment of inertia of the cylinder.

First, consider the no-slip conditions, and find the friction force $T$ and compare it to the normal force. IF $|T| \leq \mu N$ then this condition can continue (here $\mu$ is the coefficient of friction).

1. **Rolling** with ${v} + {\omega}\, r = 0$ and $\dot{v} + \dot{\omega}\, r = 0$.

   $$ \begin{aligned} N & = m g \cos x \\ T & = \tfrac{m g}{3} \sin x \\ \dot{v} & = -\tfrac{2 g}{3} \sin x \\ \dot{\omega} &= \tfrac{2 g}{3 r} \sin x \end{aligned}$$ which is maintained as long as $|T| \leq \mu N$. Using the values above this condition becomes $$ \mu \ge \tfrac{1}{3} \tan x $$
2. **Slipping uphill** with $T = \mu N$

   $$ \begin{aligned} N & = m g \cos x \\ T & = \mu m g \cos x \\ \dot{v} &= -g \sin x + \mu g \cos x \\ \dot{\omega} &= \mu \tfrac{2 g}{r} \cos x\end{aligned}$$ which is maintained as long as $v \ge -\omega\,r$.
3. **Slipping downhill** with $T = -\mu N$

   $$ \begin{aligned} N & = m g \cos x \\ T & = -\mu m g \cos x \\ \dot{v} &= -g \sin x - \mu g \cos x \\ \dot{\omega} &= -\mu \tfrac{2 g}{r} \cos x\end{aligned}$$ which is maintained as long as $v \le -\omega\,r$.